# Список в csv табличку

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Доброго всем вечера!
Помогите вывести список ['5', '18', '0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
в одну колонку csv таблицы с помошью python 3.4.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Хорошо бы увидеть, какое решение, хоть частичное, у вас уже есть на данный момент.

Answer (score 2):

Довольно странное требование — записать данные в одну колонку в csv-файл. Ведь [CSV](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV) — это такой формат представления таблицы в виде текстового файла, в котором каждая строка делится на поля определённым разделителем (например запятой). Например, поимённый список меток stackoverflow с количеством заданных вопросов мог бы начинаться вот так:

```
php;12557;18;78
javascript;8419;13;84
java;6435;9;59
```

Таким образом, если колонка в csv-файле всего одна, то задача никак бы не отличалась от "вывести элементы списка в файл, каждый на новую строчку". Разделять-то нечего.

Впрочем, автору виднее :) `Вывести список в одну колонку csv` можно вот так:

```
import csv

data = ['5', '18', '0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']

with open('list_to_csv.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for item in data:
        csv_writer.writerow([item])
```

Comment: Спасибо Alex! Всё получилось! У меня три списка подобные тому, которые я написал в вопросе. Так как, я подумал, что задача сложная записать их все в один csv в разные столбцы, то записал каждый в свой файл, а потом скопировал столбцы в один (где и поставил их паралельно друг - другу):) В связи с этим, не могли бы написать, как можно всё таки три списка в один csv засунуть, что бы элементы из трёх списков встали в соответствии друг с другом??